# How can you randomly return an element from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

in this question we are asked to randomly return an element from a list. where "rand()" is uniformly distributed from 0 to 1. "list" is a list of elements

Answer (score -1):

```
def r(lst):
    return lst[int(random.uniform(a=0,b=1)*len(lst))]
```

However `random.choice()` is easier to use

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: 1.return list[int(len(list)*rand())]
2.return list[(len(list)/rand())]
3.return list[int(rand())
4.return list[len(list)}

among these is 1 the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

You should mention in the question if there are multiple answers to choose from.

1. `return list[int(len(list)*rand())]`

   This is the correct answer. Multiplying the number of elements `len(list)` with a random number between 0 and 1 gives you a random number between `0` and `len(list)`. You use `int()` to convert the value to an integer, effectively rounding it down and then select the item at that position.
2. `return list[(len(list)/rand())]`

   This doesn't work. `len(list)` will usually be an integer > 1 and dividing that by a number between 0 and 1 always gives an even bigger number, so you always try to get an item that is after the last one in the list. Also the index will be a float, but the index must be an integer
3. `return list[int(rand()) # i assume you wanted to use a square bracket here`

   This will always select the first element. It's a random number between 0 and 1 rounded down => 0
4. `return list[len(list)}  # same thing here`

   this will always try to select the element after the last one, which results in an error. Also, this can't even be random without the rand() function ...